# Representation of Haskell's powerset type in System F

Tags: haskell, types

Haskell accepts the definition of these two types

```
data PowerPower = PP ((PowerPower -> Bool) -> Bool)
data Power = P (Power -> Bool)
```

Type `PowerPower` is used extensively in the [Reynolds' paper](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00076261/document) that refutes set semantics for System F. It is represented by this type of System F

```
PowerPower = forall A, (((A -> Bool) -> Bool) -> A) -> A
PP = \ z A f -> f (\ u -> z (\ x -> u (x A f)))
```

Reynolds' refutation ends by arguing that `PowerPower` is isomorphic to the powerset of the powerset of `PowerPower`, which contradicts [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem) about cardinals. The two nested powersets correspond to the two arrows towards `Bool` in the definition of `PowerPower`.

The refutation would be greatly simplified if we could use type `Power` instead of `PowerPower`. One powerset is enough to apply Cantor's theorem. The question then becomes: can we represent type `Power` in System F? It may be difficult, because `Power`'s underlying type functor, `\X -> (X -> Bool)`, is contravariant instead of covariant. Since Haskell accepts the definition of `Power`, we might use its representation in Haskell's memory model to derive a type in System F.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `B` be any type (`Bool`, in your case), and assume an isomorphism, with its inverse

```
iso :: P -> (P -> B)
osi :: (P -> B) -> P
```

Now, take any `f :: B->B`. We prove that `f` has a fixed point. (This is an instance of Lawvere's fixed point theorem.)

Define

```
 g :: P -> B
 g p = f (iso p p)
```

We then have (I'll leave to you to check that the following is well-typed):

```
g (osi g) = f (iso (osi g) (osi g)) = f (g (osi g))
```

Hence, `g (osi g)` is a fixed point of `f`.

In Haskell, this is not a big deal. After all we have `fix` that can always produce a (least) fixed point of any endo `f :: B->B`.

However, most typed lambda calculi like the simply-typed lambda calculus, System F, the calculus of (inductive) constructions, etc. are normalizing. There, we do not have arbitrary recursion, and the evaluation of each (closed) term always terminates, reducing to its normal form, which has a canonical shape.

If we take `B = Bool`, and `f = not`, we have that there is a boolean `b` equal to `not b`. This can not happen in such calculi (suitably extended with `Bool` if not present) since `b` would then normalize to either `True` or `False`, but neither is a fixed point.

Again, in Haskell we can take the non terminating `b = fix not`, but we do not have such option in terminating calculi.

Comment: I think you mean `f=not` at the end. I don't understand why Reynolds' didn't take 2 lines to mention this in his paper. Or Coquand for that matter, when he formalized Reynolds' proof in Coq.

Comment: @V.Semeria Indeed `f=not`. Fixed, thanks.